# Is the .hta filetype an actual program, or a file?

Tags: html, windows, exe, hta

When I was looking into the `.hta` filetype online, it appears to be referenced as a program, however I know that `mshta.exe` is the program used for them.  Does that mean `.hta` is actually just a *file* that uses mshta.exe to interpret it (effectively mshta.exe is a stripped down browser)?  Does that mean if someone created a new program to replace mshta.exe, one can have hta files open with that new program?

Comment: The [tag:hta] tag's [Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/hta/info) link has a great deal of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose if you want to be really pedantic, only .exe files with a PE header are actual programs to Windows (Windows 95/98/ME would also run DOS .exe and .com files directly). Anything else cannot be run directly by `CreateProcess` and needs some kind of interpreter.

A .hta file (HTML Application) is basically web page with some special syntax and usually some HTML and Javascript. And yes, mshta.exe is a stripped down browser (most likely hosting mshtml/trident) and could theoretically be replaced by another host program. .hta is not special in any way, anyone could [create a custom file extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/customizing-file-types-bumper) and register their interpreter as the handler for those files, it is no different than `Notepad.exe "%1"` being the default handler for .txt files...

Comment: I also did a test and when using Win+R and entering say `mshta "C:\Path\To\File\index.html"` it does, in fact load the page as if it were an `.hta` file, so that basically coincides with what you said.  And yeah, it's called an HTML _Application_ but it seems that it's basically a custom-tailored solution to run HTML content (with/without JS and CSS) in a custom browser.

Comment: Like I said read the info link which would have taken you [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - "**HTAs are full-fledged applications**. These applications are trusted and display only the menus, icons, toolbars, and title information that the web developer creates. In short, HTAs pack all the power of Internet Explorer—its object model, performance, rendering power and protocol support—without enforcing the strict security model and user interface of the browser."

Comment: The "special syntax" is the HTA specific commands like control behaviour of the application and the visual like fullscreen, appear in the taskbar the kind of things you can't normally do with HTML unless it's running in a web browser control.

Comment: @user692942 So let me see if I understand it now - an HTA would be the _application_, while mshta.exe is the _program_?

Comment: Application and program is pretty much the same thing. HTA is an early version of PWAs, a way to write "programs" using HTML and scripting. It looks like an app to the user but not to Windows which is why mshta is the real application doing the work of interpreting the .hta file.